# Does cursor adapter query db multiple times or does it cache the full result?

Tags: android, xamarin, android-cursoradapter

I'm new to android dev (xamarin) and trying to undestand the basics. So as you scroll through a list, does it hit the db as you go, or does it pick up rows from a cache.

-If it does hit the db, why would most docs say that it is more efficient than say supplying a base adapter with an ilist. At least this way I only hit the db once.

-If it doesnt and puts everything in a cache, then its similar to using a base adapter with supplied with a full list.

I'm still confused as to why most people say the cursor adapter is more efficient ?

Thanks,
Mick

Comment: From my understanding a CursorAdapter caches the full result of a query and allows you to extract individual elements from the cursor in your bindView method of the adapter class ie something like this

Comment: public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        String id = cursor.getString(0);
        String name = cursor.getString(1);
        // Get all the values
        // Use it however you need to
        TextView textView = (TextView) view;
        textView.setText(name);
    }

Comment: hi Jay, i've debugged this and base adapter goes thru that same number of loops in the GetView event, so it seems that they are both smart to bind only the 'Viewable' items (plus 1 hidden).

Answer (score 0):

No, it caches the full result.

If anyone wants to find out more about CursorAdapter he can look here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/part_4_-_using_cursoradapters/